# MySQL separate in to DIV elements

Tags: php, html, mysql

I would greatly enjoy knowing how to separate the results of my query based on the "season" using PHP only. The products should be placed in separate divs according to what season they are for. I would also like to do this in the most efficient way possible. I have thought about his for some time and have failed both in a solution and in finding someone else's similar results on the internet. Please ignore the jquery, it is a leftover for something I may or may not use.

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    include_once("config.php");
    ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Shop</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/main.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0       
    /jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery.simplyscroll.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    (function($) {
$(function() {
    $("#scroller").simplyScroll();
});
    })(jQuery);
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="container">

    <div id="header">
    <div id="menu">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="shop.php">Shop</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div id="content">

    <?php
    //current URL of the Page. cart_update.php redirects back to this URL
    $current_url = base64_encode("http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

    //$results = $db->query('SELECT id, name, thumb, description, price, season FROM products 
    BY season ASC');

foreach($db->query('SELECT id, name, thumb, description, price FROM products BY season 
    ASC') as $results){

if ($results) { 
    //output results from database
    $last_season = 1;
    echo '<div class="products">';
    while($obj = $results->fetch_object())
    {
    if ($last_season != $obj->season){
    echo '</div><div class="products">';
    }
    echo '<div class="product">'; 
    echo '<form method="post" action="cart_update.php">';
    echo '<div class="product-thumb"><img src="image/'.$obj->product_img_name.'"></div>';
    echo '<div class="product-content"><h3>'.$obj->product_name.'</h3>';
    echo '<div class="product-desc">'.$obj->product_desc.'</div>';
    echo '<div class="product-info">Price '.$currency.$obj->price.' <button 
    class="add_to_cart">Add To Cart</button></div>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="product_code" value="'.$obj->product_code.'" />';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="type" value="add" />';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="return_url" value="'.$current_url.'" />';
    echo '</form>';
    echo '</div>';

    $last_season = $obj->season;
    }
    echo '</div>';
}
}
    ?>

    <div id="shopping-cart">
    <h2>Your Shopping Cart</h2>
    <?php
    if(isset($_SESSION["products"]))
    {
    $total = 0;
    echo '<ol>';
    foreach ($_SESSION["products"] as $cart_itm)
    {
    echo '<li class="cart-itm">';
    echo '<span class="remove-itm"><a href="cart_update.php?removep='.$cart_itm["code"].'&
    return_url='.$current_url.'">&times;</a></span>';
    echo '<h3>'.$cart_itm["name"].'</h3>';
    echo '<div class="p-code">P code : '.$cart_itm["code"].'</div>';
    echo '<div class="p-qty">Qty : '.$cart_itm["qty"].'</div>';
    echo '<div class="p-price">Price :'.$currency.$cart_itm["price"].'</div>';
    echo '</li>';
    $subtotal = ($cart_itm["price"]*$cart_itm["qty"]);
    $total = ($total + $subtotal);
    }
    echo '</ol>';
    echo '<span class="check-out-txt"><strong>Total : '.$currency.$total.'</strong> <a 
    href="../page/view_cart.php">Check-out!</a></span>';
    echo '<span class="empty-cart"><a href="cart_update.php?emptycart=1&
    return_url='.$current_url.'">Empty Cart</a></span>';
    }else{
    echo 'Your Cart is empty';
    }
    ?>
    </div>

    </div>

    <div id="footer">Footer goes here.</div>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

I am getting an error on line 44, which is the start of the "foreach" statement. I am again at a loss. Thank you a ton for your help so far. If I can get this working, with help of course, I will be extremely excited and in your debt.

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: I added an answer for you to try - check it out and let me know your results!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a loop that will create a new div each time the season changes in a new row. You will need to change the query to order the results by season, e.g.

```
ORDER BY season ASC
```

Here's the loop:

```
if ($results) { 
    //output results from database

$last_season = 1; //initial value

echo '<div class="season">';  //opens first season div

 while($obj = $results->fetch_object()){

    if ($last_season != $obj->season){
        echo '</div><div class="season">';
    }

        echo '<div class="product">'; 
        echo '<form method="post" action="cart_update.php">';
        echo '<div class="product-thumb"><img src="image/'.$obj->product_img_name.'"></div>';
        echo '<div class="product-content"><h3>'.$obj->product_name.'</h3>';
        echo '<div class="product-desc">'.$obj->product_desc.'</div>';
        echo '<div class="product-info">Price '.$currency.$obj->price.' <button class="add_to_cart">Add To Cart</button></div>';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="product_code" value="'.$obj->product_code.'" />';
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="type" value="add" />';
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="return_url" value="'.$current_url.'" />';
        echo '</form>';
        echo '</div>';

        $last_season = $obj->season;
    }
    echo '</div>'; //closes final season div

}
```

Regarding the line 44 error in the foreach, I believe what you want there instead of a foreach is simply:

```
$results = $db->query('SELECT id, name, thumb, description, price FROM products BY season 
ASC'); //remember to remove the closing bracket of the foreach
```

Comment: Still having issues. Made progress though, of which I am grateful. Thanks!! See above for edited question please!

Comment: It works now without error! Now to figure out why I am not getting anything displayed on the actual page. But that is a separate matter. Thanks again!